# Leaflet set the ImageOverlay switched off at the initial stage

Tags: leaflet, javascript, image

I would like to set my overlayimage off when reload the map.

According to the link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46043995/set-leaflet-overlay-off-in-the-layer-control

I tried sth like this:

```
   var overlayMaps = (null,{
    "Geographic names": positronLabels,
    "City fibre": cityfibre
  });
```

but there is no reaction on my map

In turn this example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45333282/remove-leaflet-overlaymaps-layer-programmatically

[Esri leaflet layers turned off by default in map layer control box](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224843/esri-leaflet-layers-turned-off-by-default-in-map-layer-control-box)

shows how to remove some layer instead of switch it off at the initial stage.

When I put `null` into my code, my overlay layers are gone:

```
    L.control.layers(baseMaps, null, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

I couldn't find a good solution on the Leaflet.js reference:

https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/

Is there any option to make them switched off at the initial stages?

[image: Layers gone]

[image: Layers unchecked]

Answer (score 1):

This is a simply thing, that we must do.

the `.addTo(map)` states, that layer will be switched on as a default.

We must remove it if we want the different result:

```
    cityfibre = L.layerGroup([Peterboro, Coventry,]);//.addTo(map);
```

[image]