# Dividing GeoJSON into two separate layers in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson

Basing on this example:

http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/sports/sports.html

I would like to do the same in my case, however, my way is slightly different:

Firstly I have made a major layer disabled, moving checkboxes to the sublayers:

[image]

although only 1 sublayer is visible.

My code looks as follows:

```js
  var url = 'json/vm2.json';  // Here is the url path to my GeoJSON file, 


    function getColor(Type){   //layer 2 Virgin Media
    return Type == 'Infill' ? 'yellow' :
       Type == 'MDU' ? 'orange' :
                            'orange';
       }    
   function style(feature) {
    if (feature.properties.Type === "MDU" && 
   feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count === "")
    return{
    fillColor: '#d4a270',
    fillOpacity: '#d4a270',
    weight: 0.5
    }
   if (feature.properties.Type === "Infill" && 
    feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count === "")   
    return{
    fillColor: '#efefa9',
    fillOpacity: '#efefa9',
    weight: 0.5
    }
    else
return {
    fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Type),
    fillOpacity: 1,
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 0.75,
    //color: '#ffffff',
    //dashArray: '3'
    };
   }


   var baseball;    

  // Get GeoJSON data and create features.
   $.getJSON(url, function(data) {

    baseball = L.geoJson(data, {

        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            radius:6,
            opacity: .5,
            //color: "#000",
            color:getColor(feature.properties.Type),
            fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Type),
            fillOpacity: 0.8

            }).bindTooltip(feature.properties.Owner);
        },
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            },
            filter: function(feature, layer) {   
                return (feature.properties.Type == "Infill" );
            }
            }).addTo(map);  //Note turned on to start map with Data, Checkbox has checked property.
    });

  //2nd Layer in map
  var footballTeam; 

 // Get GeoJSON data and create features.
  $.getJSON(url, function(data2) {

    footballTeam = L.geoJson(data2, {

        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            radius:6,
            opacity: .5,
            //color: "#000",
            color:getColor(feature.properties.Type),
            fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Type),
            fillOpacity: 0.8

            }).bindTooltip(feature.properties.Owner);
        },
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            },
            filter: function(feature, layer) {   
                return (feature.properties.Type == "MDU" );
            }
            });
    });

   // Handles the check boxes being turned on/off
   document.querySelector("input[name=infill]").addEventListener('change', 
  function() {
            if(this.checked) map.addLayer(baseball)
              else map.removeLayer(baseball)
                if (clickmark != undefined) {  //i.e. if it exists...
                //function all to remove the yellow select circle, could call function to clear table from here.
                    map.removeLayer(clickmark);
                };
            })

      document.querySelector("input[name=mdu]").addEventListener('change', 
      function() {
            if(this.checked) map.addLayer(footballTeam)
              else map.removeLayer(footballTeam)
                if (clickmark != undefined) {
                    map.removeLayer(clickmark);
                };
            })
```

I don't understand why only 1st layer is visible. How about another one? Both comes from `url` relating to the 1 GeoJSON file.

The console says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node':
>   parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
>       at NewClass._updateContent (DivOverlay.js:173)
>       at NewClass.update (DivOverlay.js:116)
>       at NewClass.onAdd (DivOverlay.js:53)
>       at NewClass.onAdd (Tooltip.js:71)
>       at NewClass._layerAdd (Layer.js:110)
>       at NewClass.whenReady (Map.js:1411)
>       at NewClass.addLayer (Layer.js:172)
>       at NewClass.openTooltip (Tooltip.js:221)
>       at NewClass.openTooltip (Tooltip.js:340)
>       at NewClass._openTooltip (Tooltip.js:406)
>
> > Blockquote

and consequently this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
>       at (index):261
>
> Blockquote

At the end I would like to add my geoJSON sample:

```
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
    {
     "type": "Feature",
     "properties": {
    "Owner": 51429,
    "Type": "MDU",
    "Status": "Completed and invoiced",
    "Ticket_ID": "VM/TIK/858952",
    "NBU": 51429,
    "Address": "Sir James Knott House, Broadway West",
    "Postcode": "TS10 5AZ",
    "Date_issued_from_VM": "Wednesday, July 31, 2019",
    "Asbestos_rep": "POST 2000",
    "Planner": "Steve Levett",
    "Surveyor": "Mick",
    "STATS_Applied_for_date": "Wednesday, July 17, 2019",
    "STATS_compleeted": "Tuesday, September 10, 2019",
    "ACTUAL_Internal_QC_Date": "",
    "VM_ECD_date": "",
    "Client_Home_Count": 11,
    "Post_Survey_Home_Count": 11,
    "General_notes": "",
    "Directory": "file://Z:\\\\Fixed Line\\\\Design & Build\\\\2. 
    Clients\\\\Virgin Media\\\\2. VM MDU's\\\\2. NBUs\\\\NBU 51429 Sir James 
    Knott",
    "Sharepoint": ""
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -1.09901,
      54.60697
    ]
    }
   },
this is with Infill type
and below with MDU type
      {
       "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
    "Owner": 189154,
    "Type": "MDU",
    "Status": "Survey Date Arranged / STATS Applied",
    "Ticket_ID": "VM/TIK/831512",
    "NBU": 189154,
    "Address": "34-43 Sheppard Court, Chieveley Court",
    "Postcode": "RG31 5JF",
    "Date_issued_from_VM": "Tuesday, June 11, 2019",
    "Asbestos_rep": "POST 2000",
    "Planner": "CBJ",
    "Surveyor": "",
    "STATS_Applied_for_date": "Needed",
    "STATS_compleeted": "",
    "ACTUAL_Internal_QC_Date": "",
    "VM_ECD_date": "",
    "Client_Home_Count": 10,
    "Post_Survey_Home_Count": "",
    "General_notes": "nick.odonnell@firstport.co.uk",
    "Directory": "file://Z:\\\\Fixed Line\\\\Design & Build\\\\2. 
     Clients\\\\Virgin Media\\\\2. VM MDU's\\\\2. NBUs\\\\NBU 189154 Sheppard Court",
       "Sharepoint": ""
       },
      "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates": [
        -1.04543,
        51.45649
       ]
     }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

O gosh! Looks like I have done silly mistake, like in the query here:

[Leaflet set the ImageOverlay switched off at the initial stage](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/342672/leaflet-set-the-imageoverlay-switched-off-at-the-initial-stage)

where I should remove .addTo(map);

Now I should add it to the 2nd layer, in order to make this file running.

So the code for 2nd layer should look like this:

```
 $.getJSON(url, function(data2) {

footballTeam = L.geoJson(data2, {

    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

        return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
        radius:6,
        opacity: .5,
        //color: "#000",
        color:getColor(feature.properties.Type),
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Type),
        fillOpacity: 0.8

        }).bindTooltip(feature.properties.Owner);
    },
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        },
        filter: function(feature, layer) {   
            return (feature.properties.Type == "MDU" );
        }
        }).addTo(map);
});
```